# Hard reset will not work

Tags: iphone

My phone will not hard reset. I have an Iphone XR and I have pressed the volume up volume down buttons then held the sleep/awake button and the phone shut down. I continued to hold the sleep/awake button but instead of the connect to Iphone thing it just shuts down. I have run out of options please help.

Comment: Have you gone through the steps on [this page](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios)?

Comment: When you press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the slide to power off slider appears?  Did the slider appear?

Comment: The instructions you describe is a hard *restart* not a reset (force it to turn off/on).  If you want to *factory reset* (also called hard reset) your phone, these are the instructions:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252